# How to scroll a text?

Tags: arrays, flutter, text, dart, scroll

I have a text and I've tried a lot to make it scrollable, what I want is to make the postDesc text scrollable I've tried to wrap it with single child scroll view and listview and expanded but not worked.
please give me a solution

I want to make the screen or the container scrollable or to scroll the text only.

I've seen many solutions but it didn't work for me.

My project has been stopped because of that.

For any details you want please leave a comment.

thanks,

My Code:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userimage = InkWell(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
        height: 40.0,
        width: 40.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage('${widget.userPhoto}'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final headerDesc = Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '${widget.writer}',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          '25 minutes ago',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

    final header = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[userimage, headerDesc],
    );

    final descriptionText = Text(
      '${widget.postTitle}',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Amiri',
        color: Colors.black87,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 20,
      ),
    );

    final divider = Divider(
      thickness: 0.5,
      color: Colors.grey,
    );

    final footer = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(null);
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.share,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 30.0,
            ),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _firestore.collection('posts').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var documents = snapshot.data.documents;

                  var likes;

                  for (var document in documents) {
                    if (document.documentID == widget.uid) {
                      likes = document['likes'];
                    }
                  }
                  return Text(
                    '$likes',
                  );
                }),
            SizedBox(
              width: 3.0,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ImagePreview(
                          image: widget.networkImage,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: widget.networkImage.image,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 90.0,
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Material(
                      elevation: 5.0,
                      shadowColor: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20.0,
                            bottom: 00.0,
                            left: 20.0,
                            right: 20.0,
                          ),
                          child: ListView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              header,
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10.0,
                              ),
                              descriptionText,
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              divider,
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${widget.postDesc}',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              footer,
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          await likePost();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: where exactly is the problem? ''${widget.postDesc}'' ??

Comment: try putting it inside a container,or a Wrap()

Comment: yes the problem is in postDesc

Comment: I've tried already

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I think the problem is that you have a SingleChildScrollView inside a ListView. If you just want to scroll the postDesc, you might want to add this to your ListView:

```
ListView(
   physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   shrinkWrap: true,
   children: [...]
),
```